# problem with onConfigurationChanged in TabActivity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabactivity, android-configchanges

I have TabActivity and also three others activities in tabs. In Manifest file I have line:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
```

in `<activity>` tag of the TabActivity and also three others activities. I have also overrided in all my activities `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` method. And it works properly in almost all cases. After that the phone screen has blanked in only landscape mode and I have clicked the home button and next I want to change the orientation the method onConfigurationChanged has not been called.

I have used Toast class and I know that the only method onConfigurationChanged of TabActivity has been called at this moment, but not this method of current activity in tab. However when I change the orientatione once more finnally the onConfigurationChanged method of current activity in active tab has been called. How can I  fix this bug? My code works properly, but not in this case.

I have noticed that similar problem appears when I switch tabs in my TabActivity and change the orientation. But now I can't explain when it works and when it doesn't work. I am in stuck. I know that allways the onConfigurationChanged method of TabActivity is calling. But this method of activities in tabs - not allways.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are using toasts to notify you of configuration changes. I would suggest debugging the application and setting a breakpoint on `onConfigurationChanged` to verify that the function truly isn't being called when you expect it to.

Comment: Yes I am using Toasts to notify me of configuration changes. I have debugged my application with breakpoint on `onConfigurationChanged`. And the function truly isn't being called in case when I have phone in landscape mode, device is locked, and I unlock the device in Portrait mode and change the orientation to Landscape and now at this moment the `onConfigurationChanged` method has not been called.

Comment: I had hoped the problem was only through reflecting the change, but it appears to be more complex. If you can only reproduce it via locking/unlocking, you could manually check the configuration in `onResume()`. I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions relevant to your problem.

Comment: The callback isn't called if you: 1.) Switch to another tab (rotation=0) 2.) Rotate (rotation=90) 3.) Go back to the original tab (rotation=90) 4.) Rotate again (rotation=0) ... Seems the activity is checking for changed rotation but didn't get the event caused by the other tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this is a not fixed bug in Android TabActivity. Now, using Tabs is deprecated in Android
Android has introduced Fragments which have replaced Tabs. So apparently the problem with tabs has gone. The problem has beem swept under the rug.